# I can not understand why my console is not showing any of my output

Tags: java

my console doesn't seem to be showing any output on my projects, on some, it does at first. I am new to this so I don't understand it, this is an example of my code

```
public class TestAmazing {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Put your data type declarations below.
        int count = 0;
        double cost = 3.45;
        char choice = 'x';
        boolean goodChoice = true;
        short lowest = '5';

        // Put the code for your calculations in this method.
        // temp in a room

    }

    public void roomtemp() {
        int person = 1;
        int temp = 20 + (person);
        System.out.println("the temperature in the room is" + temp);
    }

    // nunber of jackpot ball
    public void bonusball() {
        int bonusball;
        bonusball = (int) (Math.random() * 59);
        System.out.println("the jackpot ball is " + bonusball);
        // population of china
    }

    public void currentpopulationofchina() {
        // check whether a game is finished or not
        long populationOfChina2017 = 1394200000;
        long populationexpectedincreaseto2019 = 5840000;
        long populationOfChina = populationOfChina2017 + populationexpectedincreaseto2019;
        System.out.println("the population of china is" + populationOfChina);
    }

    // check where a game is finished or not
    public void gameloadingstatus() {
        int gameLoading;
        gameLoading = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        if (gameLoading == 100) {
            System.out.println("game is ready");
        } else {
            System.out.println("game is not ready");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not call any method in your main, so no method is called so no code of method is executed, only the variable definitions

Comment: console says <terminated> TestAmazing [Java Application C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_231\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: You may learn how java works, you define methods then you need to call them in the main method

Comment: how would I add method to my main?

Comment: @JoeEmery By calling them. For example `roomTemp();`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `main` method with the following code and it should work as you are expecting:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Put your data type declarations below.
    int count = 0;
    double cost = 3.45;
    char choice = 'x';
    boolean goodChoice = true;
    short lowest = '5';

    // Put the code for your calculations in this method.
    // temp in a room
    TestAmazing t=new TestAmazing();
    t.roomtemp();
    t.bonusball();
    t.currentpopulationofchina();
    t.gameloadingstatus();
}
```

The reason why it didn't work for you is because you have missed to call the methods you have created in the class. I have added the following lines in the `main` method to complete that missing part:

```
TestAmazing t=new TestAmazing();
t.roomtemp();
t.bonusball();
t.currentpopulationofchina();
t.gameloadingstatus();
```

Answer (score 0):

None of  your methods are static, so you'll need to create an **instance** of your `TestAmazing` class, and call methods via your instance.

That might look something like:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    TestAmazing test = new TestAmazing();
    test.roomtemp();
    test.bonusball();
    // etc...
}
```

Comment from QA:

> this worked thank you! do I have to always do this and put it in the
>   same place? – Joe Emery

Not necessarily.  It depends on the requirements of your program.  If all of your methods are **STATIC** then you don't need an instance of your class.  In that case, then you'd simply call all of your methods directly from main, like this:

```
public class TestAmazing {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Put your data type declarations below.
        int count = 0;
        double cost = 3.45;
        char choice = 'x';
        boolean goodChoice = true;
        short lowest = '5';

        // Put the code for your calculations in this method.
        // temp in a room
        roomtemp();
        bonusball();
        currentpopulationofchina();
        gameloadingstatus()
    }

    public static void roomtemp() {
        int person = 1;
        int temp = 20 + (person);
        System.out.println("the temperature in the room is" + temp);
    }

    // nunber of jackpot ball
    public static void bonusball() {
        int bonusball;
        bonusball = (int) (Math.random() * 59);
        System.out.println("the jackpot ball is " + bonusball);
        // population of china
    }

    public static void currentpopulationofchina() {
        // check whether a game is finished or not
        long populationOfChina2017 = 1394200000;
        long populationexpectedincreaseto2019 = 5840000;
        long populationOfChina = populationOfChina2017 + populationexpectedincreaseto2019;
        System.out.println("the population of china is" + populationOfChina);
    }

    // check where a game is finished or not
    public static void gameloadingstatus() {
        int gameLoading;
        gameLoading = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        if (gameLoading == 100) {
            System.out.println("game is ready");
        } else {
            System.out.println("game is not ready");
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how every method has `static` in its declaration.

Comment: this worked thank you! do I have to always do this and put it in the same place?